# How can I create a UIView that displays certain information based on the button that was pressed to show the view?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I am very new to swift and currently making an app for a school project. The app is supposed to show a collection of recipes. I have begun by having a scrolling grid of buttons (stackviews and scrollviews). Each recipe is supposed to connect to a specific recipe, and when clicked segue to a view that has the information for the recipe (image, ingredients, instructions, etc.). I would like to do this by creating a a basic recipe view file that has a space for an image, title, and text. Then, depending on what button was pressed, fill in the view with the correct information and display the view.

I have figured out an alternative method that I could use, but it is very bulky and tedious. I could set up views for the ~25 different recipes separately, and link them individually to each button.

I would much rather prefer the first option, but I am not quite sure if it is even possible, or if I am just really bad at using the right search terms in google. I know many other apps have similar systems set up, for example a social media profile is the same template for everyone, just has different data displayed inside of it. 
Can anyone help me out? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UITableView` for this task and have a model array that you fill with the required data ,and for action use `didSelectRowAt` to find which cell is clicked send the data to the next VC